# jAlert doesn't show up with jQuery ajax sync

Tags: jquery, ajax, alert, synchronous

I'm using jQuery Alert Dialogs Plugin (http://abeautifulsite.net/, version 1.1) and jQuery v1.6.1. Tested on IE 11 and Chrome 41.0.x versions. There is a test code:

```
    var t = (new Date()).getTime();
    jAlert('Test message');
    console.log('Alert displayed, d=' + ((new Date()).getTime() - t));
    console.log('  Alert visible: ' + $('#popup_panel').is(":visible") + ', Overlay visible: ' + $('#popup_overlay').is(":visible") + ', d=' + ((new Date()).getTime() - t));

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://ip.jsontest.com/',
        data: { },
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        complete: function() {
            console.log('Ajax complete, d=' + ((new Date()).getTime() - t));
            $.alerts._hide();
            console.log('  Alert visible: ' + $('#popup_panel').is(":visible") + ', Overlay visible: ' + $('#popup_overlay').is(":visible") + ', d=' + ((new Date()).getTime() - t));
        }
    });
```

And the console output:

```
Alert displayed, d=8
  Alert visible: true, Overlay visible: true, d=9
Ajax complete, d=276
  Alert visible: false, Overlay visible: false, d=281
```

My problem is that when I set $.ajax async to false alert box isn't displayed. Everything works fine When async is set to true. I know what async: false means. I used it in my form for data submit. While data submit is in progress I want to display and alert box with something like "Operation in progress..." and block any user input (mouse click, keyboard Enter key, etc.). In some places of my application this works in other not and I can't figure out why.
Is there any way to ensure that UI changes are made before actual ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [bugs.jquery.com](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7464) :

> If I show a message (say..."Loading") BEFORE I make the AJAX call, I'd
>   expect it to display.
>
> The code before the call is running, but that doesn't mean you will
>   see the result immediately. If the call is truly and completely
>   synchronous, the window update might not happen until after the $.ajax
>   call completes. It wouldn't be any different than:

If you realy want to use `async:false` ajax then you may try warp it with a setTimeOut to let browser execute the code before it and see the changes before browser freeze.

```
var t = (new Date()).getTime();
    jAlert('Test message');
    console.log('Alert displayed, d=' + ((new Date()).getTime() - t));
    console.log('  Alert visible: ' + $('#popup_panel').is(":visible") + ', Overlay visible: ' + $('#popup_overlay').is(":visible") + ', d=' + ((new Date()).getTime() - t));

// do async call
setTimeout(function () {
   $.ajax({
        url: 'http://ip.jsontest.com/',
        data: { },
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        complete: function() {
            console.log('Ajax complete, d=' + ((new Date()).getTime() - t));
            $.alerts._hide();
            console.log('  Alert visible: ' + $('#popup_panel').is(":visible") + ', Overlay visible: ' + $('#popup_overlay').is(":visible") + ', d=' + ((new Date()).getTime() - t));
        }
    });
}, 20);
```

Comment: Good point. I suspected that. setTimeout doesn't seem to be very reliable solution. I think actual timeout depends on browser performance and sometimes can be too small. I think I'm going to use async ajax call and use some flag that data submit is in progress and any duplicate submits should be ignored.